# Need to turn off thumbnail recreation when synchronizing files - possible?

Tags: files, thumbnails

I brought up this issue with the developers when EE 2 first came out and at the time there was no solution. I am now wondering if anyone has created any hacks, workarounds or add-ons that solve the issue?

The problem is the fact that EE insists on recreating all thumbnails every time you synchronize an upload destination. It does not recreate small or medium images (unless you tell it to) but there's no way to avoid the thumbnail recreation, which means that a batch addition of say, 100 images, to an already large gallery will take a very long time to process since all previous images will have their thumbnails recreated.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried myself it yet, but looking at the code I'm 99% sure this will do the trick:

1. Open `system/expressionengine/controllers/cp/content_files.php`
2. Navigate to `function do_sync_files()`
3. Find the portion of code that says `$thumb_created = $this->filemanager->create_thumb` (line 1320 and following ones in EE 2.9.2)
4. Change `FALSE   // Overwrite existing thumbs` to `TRUE  // Don't overwrite existing thumbs`

Comment: Erm, and modifying core files is a good idea...?

Comment: @PeterLewis I'm not fan of modifying core files. But Linda Antonsson is asking for a hack. If you have a solution which will not involve modifying core I'm sure she will gladly accept it.

Comment: I agree with Yuri. Nothing wrong with a core patch so long as the sponsors understand the potential gotchas.

Comment: I just wanted to say sorry about the late acceptance of the answer. I already use a few core file hacks, so one more to keep track of won't hurt too much.